# Trouble with Change Data Capture in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cdc, change-data-capture

After activating CDC for a database I'm working on, the capture job fails to actually capture anything, I'm getting these kind of errors:
[image: this kind of errors]

The SQL Server is SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 on a VMWare 10.x VM, with 8GB RAM assigned.

The steps I did where basically enabling the database for cdc, and then enabling a table for it, create a modification on that table, and notice that the capture job didn't do it's work:

[image: Service errors]

Any piece of advice will be GREATLY appreciated!

**Update:**
Problem finally not solved, had to reinstall MSSQL 2008 R2, restored a db backup, enabled CDC and worked like a charm, who knows what happened there before.

- AL

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some of the errors in their entirety, not just screenshots.

Comment: All the errors are exactly as the full error displayed in the second screenshot btw